# Dataframe fillna with series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I am updating the missing values in dataframe with another column from the same dataframe. But I can't understand the behaviour.

```
    0              1        2
0   NaN         0.076733    0.378676
1   NaN         0.223911    NaN
2   NaN         0.173071    0.534397
3   NaN         0.991686    0.381196
4   0.088309    0.237683    0.003508
5   0.751860    0.494204    0.757413
6   0.630420    0.192947    0.538492
```

I am updating the `column 1` & `column 2` with `column 0` series.

```
df.fillna(df[1])
```

I would expect it to align with the label index, but it fills with a scalar value from the series instead by the series itself.

```
    0           1           2
0   0.076733    0.076733    0.378676
1   0.076733    0.223911    0.173071
2   0.076733    0.173071    0.534397
3   0.076733    0.991686    0.381196
4   0.088309    0.237683    0.003508
5   0.751860    0.494204    0.757413
6   0.630420    0.192947    0.538492
```

**Edit:**
I would expect it to output like this:

```
    0           1           2
0   0.076733    0.076733    0.378676
1   0.223911    0.223911    0.223911
2   0.173071    0.173071    0.534397
3   0.991686    0.991686    0.381196
4   0.088309    0.237683    0.003508
5   0.751860    0.494204    0.757413
6   0.630420    0.192947    0.538492
```

Can somebody please help explain what's going on here?

**Reedit**
I found a way where pandas follow what I want to do - passing a dictionary for each column, which seems quite verbose.

```
df.fillna({0:df[1],2:df[1]})
```

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: I just edited with my expected output. I expect it to align with the row labels of `df[0]`

Comment: It fills column `1` using `df[0]`'s row `1` (0.522721), and it fills column `2` using `df[0]`'s row `2` (0.012833). The reason it's a bit confusing in your example is that your rows and columns are labeled exactly the same. At the bottom of [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), there is an A/B/C/D example that's easier to understand because the rows are numbers and columns are letters.

Comment: If you want to fill row-wise per column: `df = df.apply(lambda col: col.fillna(df[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

specify method and axis

this will do

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3,4,5,6],1:[None,None,None,None,5,6],2:[None,None,3,4,5,6]})

df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)
print(df)

    0   1   2
0   1.0 1.0 1.0
1   2.0 2.0 2.0
2   3.0 3.0 3.0
3   4.0 4.0 4.0
4   5.0 5.0 5.0
5   6.0 6.0 6.0
```

for arbitrary columns

```
df[1]=np.where(df[1].isnull(),df[0],df[1])
df[2]=np.where(df[2].isnull(),df[0],df[2])
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you try with the data I shared. The answer is really irrelevant.

Comment: @RajibLochanSarkar geekay's answer works fine with your sample data and gives your expected output. what's the issue?

Comment: BTW there is an alias method for this: `df = df.ffill(axis=1)`

Comment: What if the columns interchange i.e. df[0] is now located at df[1]? The point here is how to align to a series with same row label / index.

Comment: @geekay - I really never asked for a solution / work around. I was just trying to understand why fillna is not reading the series as I was expecting. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: well the workaround is not exactly a workaround but a way of handling not just NaN but is a way to fill in values like when values are not in some kind of range like sensor readings or obvious errors .. like temp(weather) exceeding 70C at some place where it never exceeds 35.... when you would probably want to take a average of prev and succeeding column.

Answer (score 0):

It's filling your NA's according to first column (column 0 a.k.a `df[0]`).

```
        0           1           2
0   *0.895575    0.522721    0.012833
1   **0.522721    0.522721    0.012833
2   ***0.012833    0.522721    0.558843
3   0.258442    0.522721    0.772859
4   0.900045    0.026117    0.720966
5   0.913345    0.677905    0.501755
6   0.907725    0.080543    0.881279
```

So if you had NA's in the first column, it would be replaced by the value of the first row of df[0]. In your example, that value would be **0.895575**.

For NA's in your second column (`df[1]`), it's using the the second row of the column you specified (`df[0]`, the first column). So, all NA's are filled with **0.522721**

For NA's in your third column (`df[2]`), it's using the the third row of the column you specified (`df[0]`, the first column). So, all NA's are filled with **0.012833**

Hope this helps!

Edit: I suspect [geekay's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75349867/5414809) will accomplish what you had intended:

> df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)